Can an RSA 2048 public key be recovered from encrypted- and decrypted data?
I have a binary file and an encrypted file (.sgo). Can I get the public key from this data? The encryption used is RSA-2048.

Can you give the definition of the type of the file? SGO can mean a few things and it currently is not explained in the question. A reference would be doubly nice.

For textbook RSA (or with deterministic padding) and with common public exponent(s) or known public exponent, the public key can be found from a few (like 2 or 3) plaintext/cipher pair(s). The technique is that if $m_i={c_i}^e\bmod n$, then $n$ is a divisor of $\gcd\left({c_i}^e-m_i\right)$, and usually computing that $\gcd$ and pulling out the small factors will recover $n$.
If a standard/secure/randomized encryption mode is used (RSAES-OAEP, RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5, RSA-KEM) is used, or if the public exponent can't be guessed, then a working public key can't be recovered from plaintext/ciphertext pair(s).
The question does not tell what encryption is used. As far as I can tell, Silicon Graphics Object (sgo) files never are the encryption of a binary (bin) file.
